# storing id using JTables

Tags: database, joomla-3.5, jtable

I am trying to  insert the id value using JTable, however it seems like I have missed something and made the mistake while doing so. What changes do I need to make so as to get this working? Thanks in advance

```
$db = $this->getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$data = array(
['articleId'] = $this->get('id'),
['title'], 
['sharetoken']
);

$values = array($db->quote('id'), $db->quote($title), $db->quote($token));

$query
  ->insert($db->quoteName('#__share_draft'))
  ->columns($db->quoteName($data))
  ->values(implode(',', $values));


$db->setQuery($query);
$table->save($data);

return $db->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$data` needs to be just column names, not with any values.

```
$data = array('articleId', 'title', 'sharetoken');
```

and `$values` dosen't have correct `id` right now, since your are quoting just pasic string, not a value of id.

```
$values = array($db->quote($this->get('id')), $db->quote($title), $db->quote($token));
```

So, complete code should look like this:

```
$db = $this->getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$data = array('articleId', 'title', 'sharetoken');
$values = array($db->quote($this->get('id')), $db->quote($title), $db->quote($token));

$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__share_draft'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($data))
    ->values(implode(',', $values));


$db->setQuery($query);
$table->save($data);

return $db->execute();
```

You can have column names and values in same `array` (if it makes more sense to you), but this requires some changes.

For example:

```
$data = array(
  'articleId'  => $db->quote($this->get('id')),
  'title'      => $db->quote($title),
  'sharetoken' => $db->quote($token)
);

$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__share_draft'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName(array_keys($data)))
    ->values(implode(',', array_values($data)));
```

**Check if id exists in table**

```
$db = $this->getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
  ->select('*')
  ->from($db->quoteName('#__share_draft'));
  ->where($db->quoteName('articleId') . ' = '. $db->quote($this->get('id')));

$db->execute();
$num_rows = $db->getNumRows();

if ($num_rows > 0) {
  // article with this ID exists
} else {
  // article dosen't exist
}
```

Comment: Hi....What if I want to know if the id already exists in the table...what code should I write for that?...

Comment: @NikitaDhiman See my edit.

Comment: thanks...one more question. I am trying to load value from only one field in the table...This code seems to have an error.                               $db = $this->getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);

            $query
             ->select('sharetoken')
             ->from($db->quoteName('#__share_draft'))
             ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $db->quote($this->get('id')));

           $db->execute();
           $valueshow = $db->loadObject();
           echo "not a new value, the existing value is:".$valueshow;

Comment: It shows that string cannot be loaded...is there any other method to load results?

Comment: Instead of `$db->execute(); $valueshow = $db->loadObject();` you should have `$db->setQuery($query);
$valueshow = $db->loadObject();` and since you are loading `object`, you can get value with `echo $valueshow->sharetoken;`

Comment: Further reading: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase